# CSS in Fluid 960 grid system

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, 960.gs

[960](http://960.gs/) grid is great and after downloading it, I noticed that `demo.html` contains at the end examples of the `.push` and `.pull` classes like this one:

```
<div class="grid_6 push_6">
  <div class="grid_1 alpha">
    <p>
      60, class = "grid_6 push_6" => class = "grid_1 alpha"
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- end .grid_1.alpha -->
  <div class="grid_5 omega">
    <p>
      380, class="grid_6 push_6" => class="grid_5 omega"
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- end .grid_5.omega -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="grid_3 alpha">
    <p>
      220, class="grid_6 push_6" => class="grid_3 alpha"
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- end .grid_3.alpha -->
  <div class="grid_3 omega">
    <p>
      220, class="grid_6 push_6" => class="grid_3 omega"
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- end .grid_3.omega -->
</div>
<!-- end .grid_6.push_6 -->
```

**The home page gives a link to a fluid grid system** under the title ["Custom CSS Generator"](http://grids.heroku.com/) which strangely skips to include the above test (press "preview" to see a test).
I decided to add such a test as the css of the fluid grid DOES have these classes!

1) I immediately noticed that there is a problem when you try for example to set a background color in the outermost containing `DIV`: it doesn't fill the whole content to include my test (contained) cases at the bottom!
What was more strange was the fact that when I used the `.clearfix` from the css file that I took from the original site (960.gs) the problem was fixed! i.e. this one:

```
.clear {
clear: both;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
height: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container_12:before,
.container_12:after {
     content: ' ';
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
     visibility: hidden;
     font-size: 0;
     line-height: 0;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after,
.container_12:after {
     clear: both;
}
```

2) The biggest problem remain with my `DIV` test cases with classes `"grid_6 pull_6"` or `"grid_6 push_6"`, which contain DIVs that are shrinked and don't expand in their full width!

Does anybody knows a solution for a fluid grid 960 template that does succeed to present the `.pull` and `.push` classes adjacent to each other?

See my point at [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/ENeZAKo/3/): try to resize your browser (pixel sizes do not hold, use a picture as background to investigate further)

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any margins in the grid system? They could be messing you up.

Comment: Oh yes there are: every grid_i has a margin-left/right: 1%;, alpha/omega have margin-left/right: 0;

Comment: I'm towards an absolute position solution + media queries + an engine that produces such a layout but I have first to be sure for the impotence of all the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem: "percentages in block elements are based on the width of their parents".
So, even if our "alpha" and "omega" classes are also class "grid_5" or "grid_3" they take 5 or 3 columns out of 12 of their containers which are "grid_6" and NOT of their grand-parent, i.e. "container_12"; that's the big difference from the static template where the measurements are hold on pixels and have nothing to do with parents or grand-parents.

The above calculations should be considered proportionally: a "grid_6" with 1% margins left and right per grid in a-just happened-960px container = a total width of 6*60+5*20 = 460px or 47.916%*960/100 (where the width in the CSS2 box model is defined as border+padding+context and not the [broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) one of <=IE7 in quirks mode).

Taken the above result of 460px for a "grid_3" child we should measure 22.916%*460/100 = 105.41px and Chrome Developer Tools gives us almost that number as long we resize the window to reach a 960px "container_12"!

Rule of thumb: "the sum of grids in a sub-container should be equal to 12".

So, the above example should become:

```
<div class="grid_6 push_6">
   <div class="grid_2 alpha">
      <p>60, class = "grid_6 push_6" => class = "grid_2 alpha"</p>
   </div>
   <!-- end .grid_2.alpha -->
   <div class="grid_10 omega">
      <p>380, class="grid_6 push_6" => class="grid_10 omega"</p>
   </div>
   <!-- end .grid_10.omega -->
   <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="grid_6 alpha">
      <p>220, class="grid_6 push_6" => class="grid_6 alpha"</p>
   </div>
   <!-- end .grid_6.alpha -->
   <div class="grid_6 omega">
      <p>220, class="grid_6 push_6" => class="grid_6 omega"</p>
   </div>
   <!-- end .grid_6.omega -->
</div>
```

See at [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/ENeZAKo/5/).